# urls.py file in the backend folder - needs to locate index.html at frontend folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, vue.js

I need to pass the route of my index.html file from the public folder at the frontend 
to the urls.py file that is located in the backend which is in another backend folder

FOLDERS STRACTURE:

```
backend
    -> backend
        -> urls.py
frontend
    -> public
        -> index.html
```

here is where I need to put that route so python will find my index.html file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
from .routers import router
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = '../../public/index.html')),
]
```

I use VueJs in the frontend, that why I want to work organized and have dedicated frontend + backend libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django, you can config the templates folder in settings.py, then, use the path inside this folder/s. 
Like this:

```
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['PATH_OF_YOU_TEMPLATES_FOLDER'], #Probably finished in ...public/
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        # ... some options here ...
    },
},]
```

And into the url:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
from .routers import router
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'index.html')),
]
```

You need to read the documentation of django templates (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/).